# getting latitude and longitude in A-gps in android

Tags: android

1. this is my main activity for starting service function for every one
   minutes send latitude and longitude

   ```
       Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                       cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
                       Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestService.class);
                       PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this,
                               0, intent, 0);
                       AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                       alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                               60000, pintent);
   ```

**testservice class**

```
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000, 0, this);
```

working fine some mobiles .. but not working samsung and micromax mobile(showing searching gps...this mobile using A-gps) how to solve?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use this approach....

```
while(1)
{

 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                // send lat lng 

                }
            }, 60000);

}
```

Comment: @ Akash Jindal send latitude and longitude into server working fine .getting latitude and longitude some mobile not working (samsung and micromax latest version)